# Passing variables as arguments to a py file in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to pass variables to a py script in colab. `outdir` takes a folder and `target` takes a file as a as a parameter.

```
out_dir = os.path.join('outdir','my_out_dir')
target_img = os.path.join('main_folder','input','image.png')
```

This doesn't works:

```
!python projector.py --outdir="out_dir" --target="target_img" --network=blabla
```

This too:

```
!python projector.py --outdir='out_dir' --target='target_img' --network=blabla
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Yes indeed. Actually answered my own question instead of deleting in case some other folks may search with colab terms.

Answer (score 1):

TIL, You gotta put a `$` sign in front of parameters:

```
!python projector.py --outdir=$out_dir --target=$target_img --network=blabla
```